# Displaying an image in Java using Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

I'm trying to display an image in a window using Swing.

For some reason, when I run the program, the dialog box that displays contains nothing. Is there a clear reason why this is happening?

```java
public class GameScreen {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      GameView view = new GameView();
      view.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

```java
public class GameView extends JFrame {
  public MapView mapPanel;
  public void GameView() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mapPanel = new MapView();
    this.add(mapPanel);
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
 }
}
```

```
public class MapView extends JPanel {
  public MapView() {
    ImageIcon map = new ImageIcon("map.jpeg");
    JLabel mapLabel = new JLabel(map);
    this.add(mapLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}
```

On a side note, I've heard that using ../../ in file path names isn't recommended, however in most application packages the 'resources folder' is located in the parent directory of the executable files, so what is the main way people get around this?

Comment: Note this is my answer to you side note not really the question. When I need an image I usually include it in the jar file or I get the location of the jar file on the computer and then go from there to the file (there are answers on stackoverflow to help with this). But for you real question I would try to verify if you code found the file.

Comment: *"Is there a clear reason why this is happening?"*  `new ImageIcon("map.jpeg");`  For **clear** reasons, use `ImageIO.read(..)` to load images.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to draw an image on a JPanel using Swing.

[image]

In order for this code to work, you have to put the image in the same directory as the Java code.

If you want to put the image in a different directory, you have to make that directory part of the Java classpath, and add a slash to the front of the file name.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawImage implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new ImagePanel(getImage()));
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Image getImage() {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                    "StockMarket.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawImage());
    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2668799915861031723L;

        private Image image;

        public ImagePanel(Image image) {
            this.image = image;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image
                    .getHeight(null)));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }

    }

}
```